# How can I set up automatic reference resolution in AnugularJS using TypeScript with Gulp?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

I've got an AngularJS TypeScript project I set up using the [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) yeoman generator.

In the main.route.ts file there is a list of `/// <reference path="path-to-reference.ts" />`. Now by adding a tsconfig.json file I get full Intellisense across my projects but the references are required for a successful build to occur, without these entries angular does not bootstrap successfully.

Coming from the grunt world I'm used to [grunt-ts](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts) which automatically build a file of [references](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#reference).

Is there an equivalent in gulp that I can make use of? I don't particularly want to maintain this list of references manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved this.

The default templates from gulp-angular add `/// <reference path="tsfile.ts">` entries for all of the files that are generated in the default project. So I was adding entries for every typescript file I added.

You can delete all the `/// <reference="..." />` entries EXCEPT those to your ts.d.ts file and the three index.*.ts file and all works perfectly!

For completeness, the top of your index.module.ts file should read:

```
/// <reference path="../../.tmp/typings/tsd.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="index.config.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.route.ts" />
/// <reference path="index.run.ts" />
```